How do you find the screen dimensions of your design device for use in Flutter_ScreenUtil?
I am trying to learn how to use the Flutter_ScreenUtil package to make my mobile screens reactive from the web screens.
The documentation talks about designSize() but it doesn't tell you how to find the values to put into the code.
I am developing on a Windows 11 pc.
I test on the chrome browser and an Android S21 device.
Here is what I have but I got it from a YouTube video:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (context, child) =>
         MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: child,
        ),
        child: const LoginScreen(),      
    );
  }

I don't know what I should put in there for the dimensions of my draft device.
Please help, Thanks

You can find the screen size in your application design software such as Figma. If you don't have one, you can also enter your current device width and height.
